# Get random set of rows from PCollection

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataset of the form

```
user_id, date, other_columns
1, 2017-03-10, ...
2, 2017-03-10, ...
3, 2017-03-10, ...
...
```

and I need to do the following: For every row in the dataset I want to generate a new row which will contain the **current row and a random subset of N rows for the same day corresponding to different users** as following:

```
row, other_rows
{'user_id': 1, 'date': '2017-03-10', ...}, [{'user_id': 2,...},...]
{'user_id': 2, 'date': '2017-03-10', ...}, [{'user_id': 1,...},...]
...
```

I have implemented it as following, but **it is very slow** for large datasets when executed on the cloud.

```
dataset
| 'map-to-date' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['date'], x))
| 'group-by-date' >> beam.GroupByKey()
| 'generate-output' >> beam.ParDo(GenerateOutputRows())
```

where `GenerateOutputRows` is defined as:

```
class GenerateOutputRows(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        (date, rows) = element
        for r in rows:
            other_users_rows = list(filter(lambda x: x['user_id'] != r['user_id'],
                                           rows))
            yield (r, random.sample(other_users_rows, N))
```

Could you think of another more performant way for getting the desired result?

Comment: Do you actually need this to happen for every row? or just once per user-day?

Comment: Yes I need this to happen for every row. I am generating a training dataset, for a ML model, and every row will be a training sample

Comment: What's the size of your dataset and which is the slower operation? How many workers are you using? And do you have a job id?

Comment: The dataset is about 10GB. I use autoscaling for workers. The slowest operation is the filtering operation (`other_users_rows = list(filter(lambda x: x['user_id'] != r['user_id'], rows))`). If I comment this out then it runs fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see algorithmically more efficient way of doing this, unless you can provide some simplifying assumptions, e.g.:

- Within 1 date, is user_id unique or can there be multiple rows with the same user?
- If yes, then do multiple samples of other_users_rows for the same user have to be statistically independent? If no, then you can use some caching and reuse the same sample multiple times for rows with the same user_id.
- Do the other_users_rows samples for different users have to be statistically independent, or if, say, a sample for user A does not include user B, then it's okay to use exactly the same sample for user B?

In general, this is an algorithmic question rather than a Cloud Dataflow / Apache Beam question, because the bottleneck of your code is the O(rows.size()^2) loop inside GenerateOutputRows and Beam can not make that faster automatically; I would recommend going to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com for recommendations on a more efficient algorithm.